# Are asynchronous callbacks safe in a single threaded C program?

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, callback

I can't find much on the topic (in C) but it's a question I'm trying to find  a definitive answer to.

The scenario is as desctibed below.
Say we have a single-threaded C library or application that registers one or more callbacks with another multithreaded C library. The callbacks are asynchronous.

Is this safe? If so, how/why?
Specifically, what if the program is busy doing something else right when a function that it registered as a callback gets called?

Comment: You are right that this can be a problem. Therefore, it is generally only safe to call [async-signal-safe functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) from inside a signal handler.

Comment: Right, but that's signals. They take care of saving program state to registers and resuming after the execution of the signal handler.  What I'm interested in here is not signals and signal handlers but a library I've registered a callback with asynchronously calling back mg function when my program is engaged in other processing

Comment: I don't have that much experience with Linux, so I may be wrong, but generally, I don't think there is much of a difference between a signal handler and an asychronous callback function, if the asynchronous callback function can be called at any time. Of course, if the library with which you've registered the callback function makes some special guarantees about the state the program is in when the callback function is called, and specifically allows you to call a certain set of functions, then it is a different matter.

Comment: Typically, the callback should queue up its data somewhere where the 'program' can get at it when it is not otherwise engaged.  The 'somewhere' should be a thread-safe container.  On a Windows GUI , for example, the callback could post a message to the GUI input Windows message queue.  On linux, you should do similar, the actual details dependent on your app design.

Comment: Thanks. But is it necessary that the callback itself, if it only sets a thread-safe global flag or adds something to a thread-safe queue, be called in as separate thread from the main thread? I.e. in a single threaded program if this program is engaged in something else and another program calls this callback right then, in the same thread (because it's single threaded, like I said) is there a risk that the program state gets corrupted, the instructions messed up etc, or does C interleave the instructions and handle the program counter correctly? I.e. does the callback INTERRUPT the program as

Comment: It's executing other instructions ? How does C deal with this callback - a set of instructions-- suddenly being inserted into its single thread of execution at an arbitrary point?

Comment: I'll tell you what you shouldn't do for sure. Do not attempt to acquire locks/mutexes in your callback function if they can be used by your application, since doing so asynchronously in a separate context nested along the execution path of a single thread can lead to deadlock scenarios. Also, your callback function should be re-entrant, that is, it shouldn't alter global variables or data structure contents in a manner that could lead the original execution context to experience inconsistencies (when a set of accessed data do no longer represent a consistent state).

Comment: 'How does C deal with this callback - a set of instructions-- suddenly being inserted into its single thread of execution at an arbitrary point?' well, that does not happen. The callback is either executed on some unknown library thread, called in interrupt context or the 'program' thread is signaled to run the 'callback' by means,of some API that, IME, imposes constraints upon the 'program' design.